axios uses vue_publicpath infront of requests
I have a vuejs application, which is mounted to my fastapi server on the /dist path, so I accordingly set the
publicPath: '/dist/'

in vue config.
I added
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL;

to make axios use a defined BASE_URL when using my app behind a domain.
I defined axios request for example like this:
const response = await axios.post(`/api/v1/stop?id=${id}`);

Tough this gives me a browser error with 404 that it could not find the path https://sub.domain.tld/dist/api/v1/stop tough why does it place /dist beforehand.
How do I circumvent this?
only the frontend is behind /dist, the api hosted by fastapi is on /api/v1.
Thanks for any help :)


what value did you give process.env.BASE_URL.  2. are you using the exact same instance of axios as the one you modified with axios.defaults.baseURL, i.e. if you export this axios instance, it should be the instance imported wherever you do axios.post and not from 'axios'


Vue cannot use environment variables unless they are prefixed with VUE_APP_

@yoduh @phil I gave it the following value:
BASE_URL='https://sub.domain.tld' (I replace the domainnames for general ones to not expose my domain.)

I've done so now using a custom api.js axios instance:

import axios from 'axios';
 const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
});
export default api;

Now the api_calls go to the correct path, thanks a lot!
